# Getting 'misuse of aggregate function MIN()' error when I try to delete rows from a table

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I executed the following test SQL statement on my Users table and got the above mentioned error:

```
DELETE FROM Users
WHERE Username IS NOT 'Garikai' OR Username IS NOT 'Jane'
```

I don't understand where the problem is arising from as I clearly don't have the MIN() aggregate function in any part of my statement. I'm suspecting a bug on the part of the software manipulating the database (FWIW it's SQLiteStudio 3.2.1), but I may be wrong. Some insights would be appreciated.

EDIT: Here's the entire error message

> [19:49:43] Error while executing SQL query on database 'g_im': misuse
>   of aggregate function MIN()

Comment: Could you [edit] the question to include the *exact wording* of the error message you received? There may be details in there which don't mean much to you, but help others understand the problem.

Comment: That query up there (if it works) will delete ALL rows of the table. The filtering condition in the `WHERE` clause is always true. You probably want to use an `AND` instead of `OR`.

Comment: The error message has nothing to do with with the delete sql statement, unless there are triggers or any other constraints attached to the table.

Comment: Show any triggers you have on the `Users` table.

Comment: @IMSoP that's the entire error message provided on the software console besides the other part of the message which details which database the error is originating from

Comment: @TheImpaler I feel like such a dunce getting messing up on basic De Morgan's, thanks for that heads up

Comment: @forpas I don't have any `DELETE` triggers for this table

Comment: @CL. Didn't configure any `DELETE` triggers for this table

Comment: *besides the other part of the message which details which database the error is originating from* post the full message.

Comment: @forpas updated the question

Comment: As I said this error message has nothing to do with this statement. I also reproduced it in SQLiteStudio 3.2.1 and it worked fine. There must be something else you're doing that triggers this error.

Comment: Will have take a closer look

Comment: @forpas, you were right. It was a problem with a DELETE trigger in another table which was referentially linked to the `Users` table and was cascading the deletion of the matching user. I just wish the error messages would be more informative, I literally went through each individual trigger line to find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @forpas and @CL rightfully intuited in the comments, it was a trigger problem. So the error was stemming from a trigger in another table, `Groups`, which was referentially linked to the `Users` table via the foreign key `GroupMember` in the `Groups` table. The foreign key was set to cascade the deletion of records matching the deleted `Users` username hence activating the ON DELETE trigger in the `Groups` table. The DELETE trigger had the aggregate `MIN()` function in its `WHERE` clause--of which it is apparently illegal in SQLite to have aggregate functions in the `WHERE` clause--hence the error message. Here is the original trigger code (pardon the logical holes in the code as well):

```
UPDATE Group_Members
SET Role = 'Admin'
WHERE JoinDate = MIN(JoinDate) AND GroupName = OLD.GroupName
```

Here's how I finally fixed the situation:

```
UPDATE Group_Members
SET Role = 'Admin'
WHERE JoinDate = (SELECT MIN(JoinDate) FROM Group_Members WHERE GroupName = OLD.GroupName)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably want the query:

```
DELETE FROM Users
WHERE Username <> 'Garikai' AND Username <> 'Jane'
```

Comment: I agree with you @The Impaler, but it doesn't explain the weird error message. There should be another problem

Comment: Correct on the `WHERE` logic, but still the same message